# store email address as model id or as an entity property

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb

I want to store users on a custom Users NDB model, the main unique key I want to use, is the email address, because of this I wonder if using the following model could be a good option:

```py
class Users(ndb.Model):
    uid = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)                                                                                                                     
    user = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True) 
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    password = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Notice I removed the **email** from the properties, this forces me to add users using something like:

```
Users(id="any@email.tld")
```

or to query by doing:

```
user = Users.get_by_id('any@email.tld')
```

But wondering if storing also the 'email' as a property could give me some benefits, for example using the following model:

```py
class Users(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    uid = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)                                                                                                                     
    user = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True) 
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    password = ndb.StringProperty()
```

The reason I want to use the email as the unique keys is because I am using mainly OpenID for authentication.

Update:

I made some tests and if I would like to search by email, seems that I can do it like this:

```
user_key = ndb.Key('Users', 'any@email.tld')

query = Users.query(Users.key == user_key, name = 'foo').get()
```

So If I am right I could totally remove the email from the Entity and only use it as a key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit in that.

Since you already store the email as a primary ID, you can retrieve it for any `user` instance:

```
email = user.key.id()
```